# .then() vs aysnc and await protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor

I am new to protractor and have been reading up on promise chaining using the .then() function.

For example

```
 this.getContent = function(content) {
    return element.all(by.repeater('item in list')).filter(function(elem) {
        return elem.getText().then(function(text) {
            return text;
        });
    }).first();
};
```

Which works fine to get the text i'm looking for. However, how can i restructure this to use async and await instead of the the .then() function?

Every time I try i just get a element explorer and no text.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It's possibly worth noting that `async` and `await` do nothing different to promises with `then` etc. So don't expect this to "makez the codez faster" cos it won't.  `async` and `await` is just syntactic sugar for what your already doing

Comment: _"Which works fine to get the text i'm looking for"_ - The return value of `function(text) { return text; }` doesn't do anything for the `.filter()` call. The `.filter()` part does the same as: `.filter(function() { return true; })`

Comment: yeah I stripped some code from the filter function. So it is fine to use the .then() as well at await?

Answer (score -1):

You need to *mark* the function as an *async* that means that inside that function you will have asynchronous tasks, then, set the await word for each task that you want to transform into synchronous instead of keep waiting for the promise of itto be resolved.

```
this.getContent = async function(content) {
  return await element.all(by.repeater('item in list')).filter(async function(elem) {
    return await elem.getText();
  }).first();
};
```

Comment: And if you're going to use `async/await`, why wouldnt you use it on the first function too?  `await element.all...`